How to make this color gradient glass material?
I want to imitate the material shown. I have tried various things; iridscene, Glossy BSDF, messing around with layer weight, etc. I have played anround with so many values, but didn’t even come to close to it.


What does that look like at different angles? The source of the image would be very helpful here.

“iridscene, Glossy BSDF, messing around with layer weight” is not an et cetera thing as those have nothing to do with each other, and what in the Image Enhancinator 3000 is iridscene?

@TheLabCat Probably a mis-spelling of iridescense?

PIXXO 3D has just posted a quick car paint tutorial which might give you some ideas.

@GordonBrinkmann I did think of that, but it just didn’t make any sense to me. Has blender added a specific iridescence shader?

Sorry about spelling mistake

OK, so it's some sort of glass, but not completely transparent, so maybe mix Glass BSDF with rough Glossy and then it has some sort of color pattern depending on camera facing angle, so maybe use a Color Ramp after Layer Weight, and then it has a very strong specular reflection, so let's add another 0 roughness Glossy BSDF and mix it on top with Fresnel, but let's add some more strenght to it with a Math node:

And you have a basic naive approach without any volume absorption or scattering and assuming the color comes from the outer surface, which might not be the case, but it's hard to see those things in your reference photo. If the color is coming from the volume, that would also be very intense to compute more accurately and render times would probably be ridiculous. Not sure just how realistic you want it.
Keep in mind it also needs an environment to reflect so HDRI you can see I use an HDRI image for lighting.

Thank you so much brother its really close one your life saver i was using glossy bsdf but didint think about another one. thanks for help.
